# Enable grep to exactly match the regular expression

Tags: terminal, bash

Enable command 'grep' the return the regular expression matched exactly.

Command `grep` will print a line when the line contains a string that matches an expression, which not handy to search specified content.
For instance, I have vocabulary files with formatting

```
    **word**
    1. Definition:
    2. Usage
    3. Others
```

I'd like to retrieve all the words to make a wordlist within files

```
    grep '\*\*[^*]*\*\*'
```

It return bulks of content.

How to enable grep to catch only the 'word' ?

Comment: Please update the question to include desired and obtained output.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `awk`.

This command will "extract" a bulk list of words assuming it's in the format you specified above:

```
awk '/\*\*/,/\*\*/ {print substr($0, 3, length($0)-4)}' <filename>
```

---

#### Example:

For this example, assume we have a text file called `words.txt` with the following content:

```
**test**
1. Definition:
2. Usage
3. Others

**foo**
1. Definition:
2. Usage
3. Others

**bar**
1. Definition:
2. Usage
3. Others


$ awk '/\*\*/,/\*\*/ {print substr($0, 3, length($0)-4)}' words.txt

test
foo
bar
```

#### What it's Doing

- `/\*\*/,/\*\*/` This is the *pattern range*.  I could have done this by looking for the first set of asterisks (`/\*\*`) and been done, but I used a full range for completeness.  One method is no more "right" than the other.
- `{print substr($0, 3, length($0)-4)}'` This prints the subsring (of the string `**word**`) starting at the 3rd character, with a length of the whole string (`length($0)`) minus four characters (the four asterisks).
- `<filename>` This is the input file to process the `awk` command

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the output I obtained using an example file with contents I borrowed from Allan, together with your `grep` command:

[image: command line output]

At first, I thought there was no issue, as it seems to return the lines containing the word, and I assumed you wanted to keep the `**`, given how explicitly intentional it appears to be in the regexp string.

But, having read your ask more carefully, I’m now seeing that you don’t want the `**`, and only want the word(s) contained within the `**`.

To do this, you can still use your same `grep` command, then pipe it through to `tr` to have it delete the `**`:

```
grep '\*\*[^*]*\*\*' /path/to/file | tr -d '*'
```

[image: Result of the shell command]