# Use specified quantifier in grep to retrieve satisfied vocabulary

Tags: bash

I try to grab words from a file:

```
$ grep -o '\*\*[^*]*\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md | grep -v -e "Origin" -e "Etymology"
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
**the state of feeling nervous or worried that sth bad is going to happen**
**a worry or fear about sth**
**a strong feeling of wanting to do sth or of wanting sth to happen**
```

The result I intend is to get only words:

```
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```

Refactored code with specified quantifier `{,20}`:

```
$ grep -E -o '\*\*[^*]{,20}\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md
```

Unfortunately, it returns nothing.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: See this very similar and related question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320471/enable-grep-to-exactly-match-the-regular-expression/320497#320497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the full text of the file, wouldn't:

```
grep -o '\*\*[a-zA-Z]*\*\*' file
```

work?

Answer (score 1):

The re_format(7) man page says, about the braces construct:

> A bound is { followed by an unsigned decimal integer, possibly followed by , possibly followed by another unsigned decimal integer, always followed by }.

Notice that the first integer is not optional!

In other words, if you say {0,20} instead of {,20}, it should work (at least if "zero to twenty" is what you want!).